# How to use the polarization ellipse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light

I have been doing some reading on structured light and I came across the following equation that I think is used to draw the ellipse as

$$\frac{E_x^2}{E_{ox}^2}+\frac{E_y^2}{E_{oy}^2}-\frac{2E_xE_y}{E_{ox}E_{oy}}\cos\delta=\sin^2\delta$$

Where $\delta$ is given as the difference between the 2 phases

Now say that I am given the electric field components

$$E_{x}=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$
$$E_{y}=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$

If I input these into the formula above I get 0=0, thus no ellipse can be drawn. What does this mean? If I were to maybe make them different, in this case I will make $E_{y}=(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$ my ellipse formula from above gives me

$$e^{-(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{3}{4}$$

I still don't seem to get an ellipse from this

**My Attempt**

I think that maybe the expression I get after I use the above formula can be used to only get the polarization at a point (x,y) however I am not sure how that could work, since if I use the point (1,1) I now get

$$e^{-(2)}=\frac{3}{4}$$

And this is just a straight line

I appreciate all of your help

Comment: Consider this equation for a circle:  $x^2+y^2=2$.  If I am given $x=1$ and $y=1$, then I get $0=0$.

Comment: Sure, your circle would lead to 0=0, how ever what does that tell you about the polarization state? Since it means at that point there's no polarization ellipse

Comment: No, what it says is the point (1,1) is on the locus of points defined by the equation. 
 What I'm saying is  $x^2+y^2=2$ defines a relation between $x$ and $y$.   Give me an $x$, and I'll give you the related $y$.  $y=\sqrt{2-x^2}$.  When I plot all possible pairs I get a circle.  For the polarization ellipse:  give me a $E_x$ and I'll give you the related $E_y$.  When I plot all possible pairs, I get an ellipse.